# Authenticated WCF Service for MonoTouch, Mono for Android and WP7

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, xamarin.ios

Iam writing a Phone App where the end user should be able to access their own personal messages and other personal content.
Does anyone have some good ideas of how to create a service like this, should i use Soap or Rest, should i simply send the username/password with every request or ?

What would be the best choice for a service i would like to access from all three platforms and that only returns information specific to the authenticate user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a suggested alternative to WCF that's at least worth taking a look at, [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/), an open source REST Web Services Framework, is well suited for use in a mobile app and it supports the Mono platforms. It also has built-in support for [user authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization). At the very least, it offers a JSON serializer that [performs very well](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/NorthwindDatabaseRowsSerialization.1000000-times.2010-02-06.html).

There's a Wiki for ServiceStack [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki).

Comment: Hi as our current project only will be around 7 methods i would like not to introduce another framework, and it seems the same would be possible with WCF ?

Comment: Sure. Just double check the WCF features you want to use are available in MonoTouch and Mono for Android. My understanding is that it's not a 'complete' WCF implementation, but for most people covers more than enough of what's needed for it to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the support is like for MonoTouch / MonoDroid, but WCF supports secure services without adding username/password to every request manually (it actually does, but it includes it in the headers).

See this blog post for a great starting point for using WPF Custom Username/Password Validator: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/10/05/wcf-authentication-custom-username-and-password-validator.aspx